# bash metachars in pattern substitution

Tags: bash, substitution, metacharacters

I usually use the bash pattern substitution `${parameter/pattern/string}` and I wonder if there are any substitution `string` metcharacters like `&` in other tools (for instance `sed`, `awk`).

I'm trying to use the bash pattern substitution to insert `0x` just before each pair of hexadecimal digits: `1a0e22fe  --->  0x1a 0x0e 0x22 0xfe`

If `&` worked like in `sed` and `awk`, it would be so easy:

```
S=1a0e22ff
echo "${S//??/ 0x&}"
```

Are there metachars in substitution string?

Comment: Did any of the answers below work for you. Do provide feedback so that we can help you better.

Comment: Both answers work, but I already use in my scripts and that is not I was looking for. What I needed is that somebody confirm there is no bash trick to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no. This is too complex for Bash. Using a tool like `sed` instead is better.

```
input | sed 's/../0x&/g' | output
```